# Python script to check openvpn server is active or dead

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, openvpn

I am looking at the python program which will check if list of remote openvpn servers are really working!!
I tried the following code but no luck. after connecting the vpn server the control is not passing back to execute next line unless pressed `ctrl+c`. How to check below:

- If the openvpn is connecting server then print active message
- Else print not active message.
- The whole thing is in a loop and I want to run in a virtual environment.

> Code is given below

```
    path = tempfile.mkstemp()
    print('Path:',path)
    f = open(path, 'w')
    f.write(base64.b64decode(winner[-1]).decode('utf-8'))

    f.close()
    x = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'openvpn', '--config', path])
    print("\n\n Pid:",x.pid)
    try:
        print('############ inside try block############', x.pid)
        while True:
            print('############ inside while try block############', x.pid)
            time.sleep(60)

            if (x.wait() == 0):
                # died_serv_list.append(winner)
                print('\nDead server found....Exiting.....\n')
                return 
            print('############terminating the current prosses############', x.pid)
            x.send_signal(9)
            # y = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'kill', '-9', x.pid])
            break
        # termination with Ctrl+C
    except: #here issue only works with ctrl+C
        try:
            print('\n\n\n Nice server found...\n\n')
            good_serv_list.append(winner)
            print('we are inside exept.')
            x.kill()
        except:
            pass
        while x.poll() != 0:
            print('\n\n Donot know what the hell is this')
            time.sleep(1)
        print('\nVPN terminated')
```